# C++ In which case will sgetc() call underflow() - getline hangs at read()

Tags: c++

Problem:
My program(a daemon process) stuck at while(getline(fi, line)) when reading a file which was previously generated by an expect script.
When I gdb attached to my program I got a stack trace like this:

```
Thread 7 (Thread 0x7fbb0fce1700 (LWP 14465)):
#0  0x00007fbb6e48f51d in read () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007fbb6e168868 in std::__basic_file<char>::xsgetn(char*, long) () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#2  0x00007fbb6e11f455 in std::basic_filebuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >::underflow() () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#3  0x00007fbb6e12a03a in std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::getline<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, char) () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
```

Stacks of #4 is from my application code where getline is called.
By checking the libstdc++ source code and the doc of basic_streambuf Class I saw:
getline calls sgetc then sgetc may call underflow in below case:
"If the input read position is available, returns that character, otherwise calls and returns underflow(). Does not move the read position after fetching the character."

My question is in which case the input read position will be unavailable.
For my program I simply opened a file and called getline on it, why it called underflow inside and got stuck at read()?
PS: in my program the a.tmp is temp file created by mkstemp. But I can make sure this temp file is available before I finished reading it.

code snippet:

```
string cmd = "a.exp > /tmp/a.tmp";
system(cmd);
fstream fi;
fi.open("/tmp/a.tmp", ios::in);
if (!fi.is_open()) {
  return -1;
}
fi.seekg(0, ios_base::beg);
string line;
while (getline(fi, line)) {
  //do something
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The question here isn't when does sgetc() called underflow(). That is easy to answer. The real question is why read() is getting blocked. Verify that `/tmp/a.tmp` is a plain file, and not something weird. If it is, execute this program using `strace -s 256 -o strace.log <command> <arguments>`, then show the last dozen or so lines in `strace.log` before this program hangs, and the most recent logged `open()` syscall before that.

Comment: You're looking at the stuff going on inside the input buffer. It's not relevant to why the read is stuck, but basically, when the buffer is empty (you can inspect the pointers it maintains) there is a sequence of calls that results in a call to an actual input operation such as in your case `read`. All I can say by looking at the litte code you show is that (1) you should use `ifstream` not overly general `fstream`, (2) you should initialize it at declaration instead of calling `open`, (3) failure indication via return value instead of exception, is invitation to bug; (4) don't call `seekg`.

Comment: And do check the return value from `system`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, do you know in which cases read() can get blocked when reading a regular plain text file. Like another process does not finish writing to that file, or buf is not flushed? or the file contains any special content? I know read() can get blocked on a pipe, or recv blocked on a socket, but how can it be blocked on a plain text file?

Comment: No, `read()` should not be blocked when reading from a plain file. The only situation where this could happen if the filesystem is a network filesystem, and the network server is down. Why read() is stuck is completely relevant here, and I explained in my previous comment the next step in investigating it. Until you obtain the additional data that I described, this is pure speculation and a waste of time.